How to make a auto message logger in discord.js
So  im trying to make a message logger on discord.js all it does is log messages in a seperate channel in the server that its already in. ive tried to make it log every message sent but for some reason its not working
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
  if (message.guild && message.guild.id === my_guild_id) {
    const destinationChannel = client.channels.cache.get(my_chanel_id);
    if (destinationChannel) {
      destinationChannel.send(`**${message.author.tag}** said: ${message.content}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Destination channel not found in the destination guild.`);
    }
  }
});

the my_guild_id represents my server id and the my_channel_id represents the channel destination in the server

If you aren't getting any errors, try to place console.log checkpoints throughout your code to find out where execution stops.

Ok thanks im not sure what happened but i inserted console logs and now its working
